# Cakephp Model error

Tags: cakephp

I am facing a strange problem while creating edit functionality in cakephp 2.1

Error genreated:
Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2689]

My edit.ctp file is

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Task');?>
<fieldset>
<legend>Edit Task</legend>

<?php
   echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
   echo $this->Form->input('title');
   echo $this->Form->input('done');
?>

</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save');?>
```

Model: Task.php

```
 <?php
    class Task extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Task';
    }
    ?>
```

Controller :TasksController.php

```
    <?php

        class TasksController extends AppController {
            var $name = 'Tasks';
            var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
            function index() {
                $this->set('tasks', $this->Task->find('all'));
            }
            function add() {
                if (!empty($this->data)) {

                $this->Task->create();
                if($this->Task->save($this->data)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The Task has been saved');
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Task not saved.Try again.');
                }      

            }
        }
        function edit($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Task');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'), null, true);
            }
            if (empty($this->data)) {
                $this->data = $this->Task->find(array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                if ($this->Task->save($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The Task has been saved');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'), null, true);
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The Task could not be saved.Please, try again.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Could you post your relevant model and controller code? The `edit.ctp` itself isn't really helpful to determine the error.

Comment: And your controller code? It's probably best to edit your question with the code, so you can format it correctly, instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `find()` method is erroneous:

```
$this->data = $this->Task->find(array('id' => $id));
```

change to

```
$this->data = $this->Task->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: Error has been resolved but my problem is that this code does not pre populate data with id 1 in textboxes.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Did you check that `$id` is indeed one? Did you check whether your data indeed contains rows with id `1`? Do those basic checks

Comment: Yes I do have checked this. My table contains this.

Comment: run a `var_dump($this->data)` right after `$this->data = $this->Task->read(null, $id);` see if it is set correctly. I can't really help you debug this step by step.. So please do a thorough rudimentary checking

Answer (score -1):

In order to prepopulate the data on the form you need to do the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Task');?>
<fieldset>
<legend>Edit Task</legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->hidden('id', array('value' => $this->data[0]['Task']['id']));
echo $this->Form->input('title', array('value' => $this->data[0]['Task']['title']));
echo $this->Form->input('done', array('value' => $this->data[0]['Task']['done']));
//var_dump($this->data[0]['Task']['id']);
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link('List All Tasks', array('action'=>'index')); ?><br />
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Add Task', array('action'=>'add')); ?><br />
<?php echo $this->Html->link('List Done Tasks', array('action'=>'index')); ?><br />
<?php echo $this->Html->link('List Pending Tasks', array('action'=>'index')); ?><br />
```

Comment: That's not true. CakePHP does it for you if your controller and model are set up correctly.